# If the Notice: Undefined offset is happe in php then go to url?

Tags: php

I want to make error handler.It looks like this

```
function get($a,$b,$c){
     $y = explode($b,$a);
     $x = explode($c,$y[1]);

    return $x[0];   
}
if (!isset($contents)) {

$hiren =get($contents,'<plaintext>','</plaintext>');

 echo  "<p id=\"example2\"><font size=\"60\">".get($contents,'<plaintext>','</plaintext>'). "</font></p>";

 }
 else{
     header( "Location: error.php" );
 }
```

but it is not working.

I want when the Notice: Undefined offset type of error occurs.I want to go to error.php. what i am doing wrong?

Comment: `if (!isset($contents))` is that right condition?? i think i should be `if (isset($contents) && !empty($contents))`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is this:

```
function get($a,$b,$c){
     $y = explode($b,$a);
     if (!isset($y[1]))
         return false;
     $x = explode($c,$y[1]);

    return $x[0];
}
```

Now you check via, `if ($hiren === false)`, meaning it didn't find the string in-between.